# Ocurrió un error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, html, api, port

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy creando un script web que permita hacer el chequeo de una direccion ip y un puerto, para verificar si esta abierto o cerrado, estoy utilizando la API de GeekFlare y cuando le doy click al boton me arroja el siguiente error
**Ocurrió un error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Verificar puerto abierto</title>
    <!-- Agregar las bibliotecas de Bootstrap y jQuery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function verificarPuerto() {
            const apiKey = 'XX'; // Ingresa tu clave de API aquí
            const ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
            const port = document.getElementById("port").value;

            fetch(`https://api.geekflare.com/v1/portscanner?host=${ip}&startport=${port}&endport=${port}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                if (data.ports[port] === 'open') {
                  $('#resultado').html(`<p>El puerto ${port} está abierto en ${ip}.</p>`);
                } else if (data.ports[port] === 'closed') {
                  $('#resultado').html(`<p>El puerto ${port} está cerrado en ${ip}.</p>`);
                } else {
                  $('#resultado').html(`<p>No se pudo determinar si el puerto ${port} está abierto o cerrado en ${ip}.</p>`);
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                $('#resultado').html(`<p>Ocurrió un error: ${error}</p>`);
              });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Verificar puerto abierto</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ip">Dirección IP:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip" name="ip" placeholder="IP">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="port">Puerto:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="port" name="port" placeholder="Puerto">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verificarPuerto()">Verificar</button>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Podran iluminarme e indicarme que estoy haciendo mal? desde ya gracias.
Estoy utilizando Wamp Server 3.3.0

Comment: probaste configurando la solicitud en modo 'no-cors' en las opciones del fetch?

Comment: Hola infinit3Loop, estoy intentando agregar la solicitud fetch con modo no-cors de la siguiente manera y me da el mismo error, existe otra forma?
**fetch(`https://api.geekflare.com/v1/portscanner?host=${ip}&startport=${port}&endport=${port}&apikey=${apiKey}`, { mode: "no-cors" })**

Comment: Tambien probe lo siguiente agregue la siguiente linea
const url = `https://api.geekflare.com/v1/portscanner?host=${ip}&startport=${port}&endport=${port}&apikey=${apiKey}`;
y el fetch lo deje de la siguiente manera:
fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors" })

pero me sigue dando el mismo error.